# App crash with proguard activated

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have finished my app but when i try to build with

```
minifyEnabled true
```

It crash.

My **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
}
```

I have not edited other files. I have searched on Google but I can't resolve it. Thank you in advance!

LOG:

http://pastebin.com/d7i4YUsK
(Log is a big text)

Proguard.config is this?

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

SOLVED:
I have found the solution:

```
    -optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment



-keep public class org.spongycastle.** {
  <fields>;
  <methods>;
}

-keep public class org.apache.** {
  <fields>;
  <methods>;
}

-ignorewarnings

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}


-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Comment: add the crash reports and also proguard config.

Comment: Hi , i have edited 1st post. I have no edited other files

Comment: No this is not proguard file, check in your project's root folder.

Comment: This may happen when using a custom library with JNI classes inside. If this is your case, please add the package to the exclusion list in Proguard.

Comment: The file you are looking for is `proguard-android.txt`.

Comment: i have edited my post. The file proguard-android.txt is in SDk/tools/proguard

Comment: Solved! i have edited my post. On stackoverflow i have found a similar problem. I have edited my proguard-rules!

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please place the answer below as an answer instead of an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
        -optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment



-keep public class org.spongycastle.** {
  <fields>;
  <methods>;
}

-keep public class org.apache.** {
  <fields>;
  <methods>;
}

-ignorewarnings

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}


-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```